# 'home mixed' wholewheat flour

Tags: baking

I live in Indonesia now and there is no wholewheat flour in the shops. You can buy a ground husk 'supplement' to blend with white flour. Question is, how much husk to mix with how much flour?

Answer (score 1):

It would be ideal if you could find both wheat germ and wheat bran, but substitutes may be good enough.  I'm not sure what's in your ground husk supplement, but I'm betting it's close enough to wheat bran.  Can you find oat bran, rice bran, or ground flax?  They may work as a [substitute for the wheat germ](http://www.livestrong.com/article/492671-wheat-germ-substitutes-in-baked-goods/).

[Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham_flour#Availability_and_alternatives), "Wheat consists of approximately 83% endosperm, 14.5% bran, and 2.5% germ by mass. For sifted, unbleached white flour, wheat bran, and wheat germ having densities of 125, 50, and 80 grams/cup, respectively, one cup of graham flour is approximately equivalent to 84 g (~2⁄3 cup) white flour, 15 g (slightly less than 1⁄3 cup) wheat bran, and 2.5 g (1.5 teaspoons) wheat germ."  (Graham flour contains these ingredients in the same proportions as whole wheat flour.)

If you can't find wheat germ (or a suitable substitute), try leaving it out and see what happens.